# Web SQL get last record from second table

Tags: sql, web-sql

I have 2 tables like that

ChatList Table
COLUMNS : ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, PHONE, DISPLAYNAME, SESSIONID

Messages Table
COLUMNS : ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, [DATETIME], [FROM], [TO], [TYPE], [MESSAGE], [ISGROUP], [GROUPID], [READED], [SESSIONID], [MESSAGEID], [DISPLAYNAME]

I want get last record from messages table to chatlist join

```
SELECT m.ID as MID, m.DATETIME, c.ID, c.DISPLAYNAME, c.PHONE, c.SESSIONID, m.TYPE, m.MESSAGE
FROM [CHATLIST] as c
   , [MESSAGES] as m
WHERE m.SESSIONID = c.SESSIONID
GROUP BY c.SESSIONID
ORDER BY MID DESC
```

It's not working

Comment: Whats the output that you are getting with your query?

Comment: When GROUP BY is specified, each selected column must either also be listed in the GROUP BY clause, or be argument to a set function.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the LIMIT

```
SELECT m.ID as MID, m.DATETIME, c.ID, c.DISPLAYNAME, c.PHONE, c.SESSIONID, 
m.TYPE, m.MESSAGE
    FROM [CHATLIST] as c, [MESSAGES] as m
    WHERE m.SESSIONID = c.SESSIONID
    GROUP BY c.SESSIONID
    ORDER BY MID DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I just want to get 1 record from message table not all

Comment: Yeah, that should get you only the first row in your query

Comment: If you want to get a record from message table only just remove the CHATLIST columns from select statement and add `m.*`

Comment: It's like join query  I want get datas from chatlist table  and get related last message from messages table